# SharePoint SPFX: Is there a way to get a document library by it's url?

Tags: sharepoint, frameworks, spfx, pnp-js

I was wondering if there is a way in SPFX to get the library by the current url?
Lets say "/sites/CustomerSite/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx"

Answer (score 1):

Below code works by @pnp/sp.

```
sp.web.getList("/sites/lee/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx").get().then(data => {
      console.log(data);
  }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
  });
```